# How can I actually see the raw query generated by DBI::dbWriteTable?

Tags: r, r-dbi

I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve the SQL query which `dbWriteTable` sends to the DBMS. For example, for the following example. Is there a way to get the query?

```
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars[1:10, ])
dbDisconnect(con)
```

**EDIT: 2016-11-11**

As a Postgres user, I would be most interested in the commands sent using `RPostegreSQL`. Following @krlmlr, I figured that there is a function `postgresqlCopyInDataframe`which itself calls the C function `RS_PostgreSQL_CopyInDataframe`. So I hit a dead-end here as C is beyond my skills. Any ideas welcome...

Answer (score 4):

The development version of `RSQLite`, which will soon hit CRAN, uses `DBI::sqlCreateTable()`. This function returns SQL that creates a particular table:

```
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
sqlCreateTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars[1:10, ])
dbDisconnect(con)
```

For other drivers you could look up the method definition in the driver's source code, e.g., via `showMethods("dbWriteTable", includeDefs = TRUE)` and proceed from there.